# PowerPoint Drag n' Drop Code - Modifications to affect multiple slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've been working through a YouTube tutorial for creating a Drag and Drop game in PowerPoint using VBA, and have got the VBA code working as expected, but I'm wondering if anyone could give me some advice on how to add to the code in order to do something that I'm trying to do. I have some programming experience in Python, but no experience scripting PPT files or VBA. Any help you can give here would be appreciated!

What I'm trying to do is apply the code to multiple slides in the same presentation. For example, I want to have some items on one slide be affected by the Drag and Drop code, and then move on to the next slide and do the same with other items. From looking at the code, and from my understanding, it's the sections that have

ActivePresentation.Slides(2)

that are what needs changing. Now, I know that the (2) refers to the slide number, but could you advise what to change this to in order for it to work on ANY slide number (I'm guessing this would need to refer to the current slide somehow). I've tried various commands that I've found online, but none seem to do what I want - anything I enter in the brackets that looks like it should affect the current slide results in the drag and drop not working at all on any slide, including the original slide that was working before the change to the code.

The relevant code is below:

```
    Sub DragAndDrop(selectedShape As Shape)
  
  obj_end = selectedShape.Name + "_end"
  
  dragMode = Not dragMode
  DoEvents
  ' If the shape has text and we're starting to drag, copy it with its formatting to the clipboard
  If selectedShape.HasTextFrame And dragMode Then selectedShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Copy
  
  dx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SCREENX)
  dy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_SCREENY)
  
  ' Shirt start position
  objStart.X = selectedShape.left
  objStart.Y = selectedShape.top
  
  objEnd.X = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes(obj_end).left
  objEnd.Y = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes(obj_end).top
  
  'objEnd.X = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(obj_end).left
  'objEnd.Y = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(obj_end).top
  
  Drag selectedShape

  ' Paste the original text while maintaining its formatting, back to the shape
  If selectedShape.HasTextFrame Then selectedShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paste
  DoEvents
End Sub


 
Private Sub Drag(selectedShape As Shape)
  #If VBA7 Then
    Dim mWnd As LongPtr
  #Else
    Dim mWnd As Long
  #End If
  Dim sx As Long, sy As Long
  Dim WR As RECT ' Slide Show Window rectangle
  Dim StartTime As Single
  ' Change this value to change the timer to automatically drop the shape (can by integer or decimal)
  Const DropInSeconds = 2
  
  ' Get the system cursor coordinates
  GetCursorPos mPoint
  ' Find a handle to the window that the cursor is over
  mWnd = WindowFromPoint(mPoint.X, mPoint.Y)
  ' Get the dimensions of the window
  GetWindowRect mWnd, WR
  sx = WR.lLeft
  sy = WR.lTop
  Debug.Print sx, sy
  
  With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
    dx = (WR.lRight - WR.lLeft) / .SlideWidth
    dy = (WR.lBottom - WR.lTop) / .SlideHeight
    Select Case True
      Case dx > dy
        sx = sx + (dx - dy) * .SlideWidth / 2
        dx = dy
      Case dy > dx
        sy = sy + (dy - dx) * .SlideHeight / 2
        dy = dx
    End Select
  End With
 
  StartTime = Timer
  
  While dragMode
    GetCursorPos mPoint
    selectedShape.left = (mPoint.X - sx) / dx - selectedShape.Width / 2
    selectedShape.top = (mPoint.Y - sy) / dy - selectedShape.Height / 2
    
    Dim left As Integer
    Dim top As Integer
    left = selectedShape.left
    top = selectedShape.top
        
        
    ' Comment out the next line if you do NOT want to show the countdown text within the shape
    If selectedShape.HasTextFrame Then selectedShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CInt(DropInSeconds - (Timer - StartTime))
     
         ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes("lblInfo").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CInt(DropInSeconds - (Timer - StartTime))
         'ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("lblInfo").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CInt(DropInSeconds - (Timer - StartTime))
         
    
    DoEvents
    If Timer > StartTime + DropInSeconds Then
     dragMode = False

     With ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes(obj_end) ' EXAMPLE:square_end is where you want the square to land
         If selectedShape.left >= .left And selectedShape.top >= .top And (selectedShape.left + selectedShape.Width) <= (.left + .Width) And (selectedShape.top + selectedShape.Height) <= (.top + .Height) Then
           ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes("talk").TextFrame.TextRange = "Got it! Great job!"
           'totalPoints = totalPoints + 1
         Else
         ' Try again
           selectedShape.left = objStart.X
           selectedShape.top = objStart.Y
           ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.View.Slide.SlideNumber).Shapes("talk").TextFrame.TextRange = "Sorry! Try again!"
           
        End If
     End With
     
    End If

    
  Wend
  DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems that the supposed problem line "ActivePresentation.Slides(2)" appears only in comments. In any case, if you need a reference to the slide that selectedShape is on, you can use selectedShape.Parent

Comment: I’ll try that at the weekend and get back to you. Thanks! The commented lines are just something I forgot to uncomment when posting here…they are the original lines of code, which I copied, changed, found didn’t work and deleted. They are active in the original file!

Comment: Assuming I’ve put that in the correct place, in the brackets replacing the slide number, that doesn’t work. None of the drag and drop on any slide, the original or otherwise, works at all.

Comment: How is the code triggered in the first place?